# No group of order 2907 is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Show that any Group of order 2907 is not a simple group?
2907= 3*3*17*19 
 I've started with the Sylow 19-subgroup, then the 17-subgroups and finally the 3-subgroups 
 but i couldn't proceed in the proof to find the nontrivial normal subgroup! Please help.

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan i'm not much familiar with writing using mathematics symbols ! What i did is that I found the number of each sylow subgroup, but couldn't find a way to find a normal one.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help.

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan thank u :) but i prefer to finish my studying for my midterm exam now, then i'll be ready to learn anything else!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the $19$-Sylow subgroup(s) isn't(aren't) normal. Are there enough elements left over for the $17$-Sylow subgroup(s) to not be normal? And vice versa.

Comment: i found that we have 153*18 = 2754 subgroup of order 19 . But then we still have 153 elements ! where is the problem then?

Comment: If the $17$-Sylow subgroups aren't normal, how many of them are there?

Comment: I found a problem while counting the sylow 17-subgroups 
 there number is of the form 17k+1 that divides 9 * 19 
so k=0 or k=10 which implies that we have a 171 * 16 = 2736 subgroups of order 17 
which contradicts the total number which is 2907

Comment: Right. If the $19$-Sylow subgroups aren't normal, there isn't enough space left for $171$ $17$-Sylow subgroups, so the $17$-Sylow subgroup then must be normal.

Comment: just simply as this? i mean there is no need to find the form of the normal subgroup such as H1 intersection with H2 for any H1 and H2 sylow subgroups of order 17 for example , or any thing else like Ng(  H1 intersection with H2 )

Comment: No, all we need is to show that there must be some normal subgroup other than $\{e\}$ and $G$. Element counting is often an efficient method to do that.

Comment: Thank u so much :)) i got it ! and I've finished the question solution, thank u again.